# onItemSelectedListener is not fired when i select the same previous value

Tags: android

When i am selecteing the same value again which is in adapter the values are not refreshed and even onItemSelectedListener or NothingSelected not fired

Here follows my code:

```
      spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {                  
                new MyBackgroundAsyncTask().execute();
        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                new MyBackgroundAsyncTask().execute();
        }
    });
```

Comment: You are not selecting if it is already selected, you are purely clicking.  You may need to set up a click listener instead for these situations.

Comment: ok. how to set click listener for the spinner . when i try toset the listener it gets a exception says that dont create setonclicklistener.

Comment: why would you need to reselect a selected item?  You could check the currently selected item instead if this is what you are actually trying to do?  I'm not really sure I understand what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class NoDefaultSpinner extends android.widget.Spinner {

private static Method s_pSelectionChangedMethod = null;

private int key = 0;
static { 
    try {               
        Class noparams[] = {};
        Class targetClass = AdapterView.class;
        s_pSelectionChangedMethod = targetClass.getDeclaredMethod("selectionChanged", noparams);            

        if (s_pSelectionChangedMethod != null) {
            s_pSelectionChangedMethod.setAccessible(true);              
        }

    } catch( Exception e ) {
        Log.e("Custom spinner, reflection bug:", e.getMessage());
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public NoDefaultSpinner(Context context) {      
    super(context);
}

public NoDefaultSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public NoDefaultSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {    
    super.onClick(dialog, which);   
     // Here my code goes.....

}
```

Comment: jus extend the spinner class and overide onclickListener. and it will work.

Dont forget mention in your xml spinner declaration.